# Sweetalert com load - verificar se foi executado (php - jquery - ajax - sweetalert)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

Quero que após carregar o arquivo PHP **relatorios_excel.php** feche a swal, até essa parte tá funcionando.

O **Problema** é que quando termina de carregar não gera o download do arquivo(**relatorios_excel.php**) xls.

**Código - js:** 
 function btnXLS() {

```
swal('Gerando arquivo XLS');
        swal.showLoading();
        jQuery.get("library/common/relatorios_excel.php", "act=relatorio-excel-prospect", function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            swal.close();
        });
```

}

**Código - PHP** (**relatorios_excel.php**): //Arquivo que gera o xls.

```
if (isset($_GET['ProspectPorPeriodoGerado'])) {
                $prospects = $prospectDAO->ListaProspectPorPeriodoGerado();
            } else {
                $prospects = $prospectDAO->ExecutaSQL($_SESSION["string_sql"]); //$_SESSION["string_sql"] - Sessão que armazena a query em table_prospects.php
            }
            $excel = "
            <table border=\"1\">
                <tr style=\"height: 150px;\">
                    <td style=\"width: 150px;\" align=center><img src='$logotipo'></td>                
                    <td colspan=8 style=\"text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><font style=\"font-size: 25px;\"><b>$title</b></font></td>
                </tr>            
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=9 style=\"height: 50px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;\">
                        <font style=\"font-size: 18px;\"><b>RELATÓRIO DE PROSPECTS</b></font>
                    </td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td style=\"height: 30px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><b>CRIADO EM</b></td>
                    <td style=\"height: 30px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><b>NOME</b></td>
                    <td style=\"height: 30px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><b>TELEFONE</b></td>
                    <td style=\"height: 30px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><b>E-MAIL</b></td>
                    <td style=\"height: 30px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><b>RESPONSÁVEL</b></td>
                    <td style=\"height: 30px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><b>INTERESSE</b></td>
                    <td style=\"height: 30px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><b>GRUPO</b></td>          
                    <td style=\"height: 30px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><b>ORIGEM</b></td>
                    <td style=\"height: 30px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\"><b>ATENDENTE</b></td>
                </tr>
            ";
            while ($arrayProspect = mysql_fetch_array($prospects)) {
                //Nome
                if ($arrayProspect["nome"] == "") {
                    $arrayProspect["nome"] = "Não Informado";
                }
                $nome = $arrayProspect["nome"];
                //Telefone
                if ($arrayProspect["telefone"] == "") {
                    $arrayProspect["telefone"] = "Não Informado";
                }
                $telefone = $arrayProspect["telefone"];
                //E-mail
                if ($arrayProspect["email"] == "") {
                    $arrayProspect["email"] = "E-mail Pendente";
                }
                $email = $arrayProspect["email"];
                //Responsável / E-mail
                if ($arrayProspect["responsavel"] == "") {
                    $arrayProspect["responsavel"] = "Não Informado";
                }
                if ($arrayProspect["responsavel_email"] == "") {
                    $arrayProspect["responsavel_email"] = "<span>E-mail Pendente</span>";
                }
                $responsavelEmail = $arrayProspect["responsavel"] . "<br>" . $arrayProspect["responsavel_email"] . "";
                //Situação
                if ($arrayProspect["lead"] == 0) {
                    $situacao = "Outros";
                }
                if ($arrayProspect["lead"] == 1) {
                    $situacao = "Leads";
                }
                //Interesse
                $interesse = $oportunidadeDAO->oportunidadeInteresse($arrayProspect["id"]);
                $excel .= "
                <tr>
                    <td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;\">" . $arrayProspect["criado_em"] . "</td>
                    <td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;\">" . $nome . "</td>
                    <td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;\">" . $telefone . "</td>
                    <td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;\">" . $email . "</td>
                    <td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;\">" . $responsavelEmail . "</td>
                    <td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;\">" . $interesse . "</td>
                    <td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;\">" . $arrayProspect["grupo"] . "</td>
                    <td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;\">" . $situacao . "</td>
                    <td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;\">" . $arrayProspect["nome_atendente"] . "</td>
                </tr>
                ";
            }
            $excel .= "
                <tr><td colspan=9></td></tr>                
                <tr><td colspan=9 style=\"font-size: 13px; background-color: #ddd; color: #333;\">$footer</td></tr>
            </table>
            ";
            $arquivo = "relatorio-excel-prospects.xls";
            header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
            header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"");
            header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
            echo utf8_decode($excel);
            exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**RESOLVIDO**)

Não sei se é a maneira correta, mas até o momento tá servindo para mim.
obs: Se estiver uma maneira melhor de desenvolver só deixar suas respostas. obrigado!

**Código js:**

```
swal('Gerando arquivo XLS');
        swal.showLoading();
        jQuery.get("library/common/relatorios_excel.php", "act=relatorio-excel-prospect", function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            swal.close();
        });
```

Esse código está verificando o carregamento do arquivo **relatorios_excel.php**.

A única coisa que fiz foi:

**Antes:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="btnXLSProspectPorPeriodoGerado('<?php echo $filtro_array["filtrar"]; ?>')">
        <span class="icon-file"></span> XLS Por Periodo Gerado
     </a>
```

**Depois:**

```
<a href="library/common/relatorios_excel.php?act=relatorio-excel-prospect&ProspectPorPeriodoGerado" onclick="btnXLSProspectPorPeriodoGerado('<?php echo $filtro_array["filtrar"]; ?>')">
                      <span class="icon-file"></span> XLS Por Periodo Gerado
                                    </a>
```

Como o **Código js** está verificando se o arquivo(url) foi carregado, só passei o link direto no **href** do botão, pois será executado a verificação se o arquivo(url) foi carregado e ao mesmo tempo será carregado o download. com isso após o carregamento a swal de load irá fechar e após irá iniciar o download do xls.